# Cannot log in to the MySQL server through browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Each time when I try to access the phpmyadmin from browser I receive this error:
"Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

I tried to change networks, restart docker.

```
version: '3'

services:
 web: 
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
   - 80:80
  volumes:
   - ./public_html:/public_html
   - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  networks:
   - nginxphp

 php:
  image: php:7.1.11-fpm-alpine
  volumes:
   - ./public_html:/public_html
  expose:
   - 9000
  networks:
   - nginxphp

 db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports:
   - "8080:80"

networks:
    nginxphp:
```

Cannot log in to the MySQL server
mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Docker user!

Your didn't mention if you're using the browser on the same computer as the sever or remotely. You'll need access to the mysql server (mysqld) through a terminal (command prompt). If this is a new install, it must be on the computer that is running mysql server.

In the Docker mysql page:
"The default configuration for MySQL can be found in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which may include additional directories such as /etc/mysql/conf.d or /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d."

Try looking in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file on the server you're trying access. first. You're looking for:

```
bind-address = x.x.x.x
```

This is the address that the mysql server will talk to ("bound to"). Its typically "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

To eliminate the error message like you see, I had to do two things:

1) change 'bind-address to 0.0.0.0'
this allows the server to connect to any computer. However, THIS IS A SECURITY RISK. Once you get it working, go read about bind addresses on the mysql website and set it appropriately.

2) Create an new account user@ipaddr where user is the new username and IPAddress is the ip4 address of the computer your trying to connect from. i.e.:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'192.168.1.68' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'192.168.1.68';
```

Now try accessing mysql through the terminal program using the new username on the computer with the ip you entered above by typing:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword -hx.x.x.x
```

Hopefully, this will help point you in the right direction. There's a ton of information about bind addresses and security on the web.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpmyadmin with latest mysql version you will have some login issues:

Cannot log in to the MySQL server mysqli_real_connect(): 
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): 
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

The solution is to downgrade to mysql 5.7 or another. 
I tested with mysql 5.7 and it works for me.
If you want to can test with another versions and let the community know.

Below is the docker-compose file that builds and run Nginx + php 7.1 + mysql 5.7 +phpmyadmin

```
version: '3'

services:

 web: 
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
   - 80:80
  volumes:
   - ./public_html:/public_html
   - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  networks:
   - nginxphp

 php:
  image: php:7.1.11-fpm-alpine
  volumes:
   - ./public_html:/public_html
  expose:
   - 9000
  networks:
   - nginxphp

 db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
   - db
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: db
    PMA_PORT: 3306
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports:
   - "8080:80"

networks:
    nginxphp:
```

Hope this will save some time to someone!

Answer (score -1):

Because the `phpmyadmin` container has connected to the default host `localhost`. But your mysql server is located in other container (it means you cannot connect to mysql server by using localhost). So in the `phpmyadmin` service, you have to set `PMA_HOST=db`. See full env variables: https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/

Full docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
 web: 
  image: nginx:alpine
  ports:
   - 80:80
  volumes:
   - ./public_html:/public_html
   - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  networks:
   - nginxphp

 php:
  image: php:7.1.11-fpm-alpine
  volumes:
   - ./public_html:/public_html
  expose:
   - 9000
  networks:
   - nginxphp

 db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
 phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: db
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
  depends_on:
   - db
  ports:
   - "8080:80"

networks:
    nginxphp:
```

Comment: I tried with this code but it didn't work. I received the same error.